# Inject rendered Node Express route into response of another route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Brief Project Overview**

I am working on a full page caching system using Node and Express. I have this working, however I am trying to add cache "hole-punching", where portions of a document can have different caching policies.

**Attempted Approach**

I am attempting to achieve this by injecting the rendered output of one Express route into the rendered output of another Express route. Unfortunately, the most popular methods of firing an http request within Node involve asynchronous promises. I have not been able to get promises working in a synchronous request because... well, they don't work that way.

From what I can tell, I am left with 2 options:

1. Make the entire route/request/response asynchronous (is this possible?)
2. Find a synchronous way of rendering an Express route

I don't know how to achieve either of these. I know many folks will say not to do #2 because  performance - I'm open to other suggestions.

**Code**

In the code below, I override the res.render() method to analyze the output of the current response and determine if there is a secondary request that should be made, rendered, and injected.

```
async function getRemoteInclude(req, content) {
    // remote include format: {{ includeRemote('path') }}
    const handlebarRegex = '(?<={{)(.*?)(?=}})';
    const includeRegex = '(?<=includeRemote[(])(.*?)(?=[)])';
    const replaceHandlebarRegex = /\{\{[^\}]+\}\}/g;
    let parsedContent = content;

    let foundHandlebars = content.match(handlebarRegex); // does string with {{ * }} exist?

    if (foundHandlebars) {
        let foundInclude = foundHandlebars[0].match(includeRegex); // does string with includeRemote('*') exist?

        if (foundInclude) {
            const axios = require('axios');
            let path = 'http://expresscache.com:3000/test'; // sample hardcoded route

            let response = await axios.get(path); // fire async request to express route

            return parsedContent.replace(replaceHandlebarRegex, response.body); // replace remote include string with route response
        }
    }

    return content;
}

function interceptRender() {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        res.render = function (view, options, callback) {
            var self = this;
            options = options || res.locals;

            self.app.render(view, options, function (err, content) {
                if (!callback) {
                    content = getRemoteInclude(req, content); // check if content should be modified with rendered remote include
                    self.locals.body = content;
                    self.send(content);
                } else {
                    callback();
                }
            });
        }

        next();
    }
}

module.exports = {
    interceptRender: interceptRender
};
```

Obviously this code performs an async request through use of the axios node library. I am expecting that this will not be part of the final solution, unless option 1 from above is possible.

**Ask**

Does anyone have an idea how to either get this async request working in a synchronous context or to modify this request so that it is synchronous itself? Or maybe a completely different approach?

Comment: Express supports asynchronous middleware, so all you will need to do is make the returning function of `interceptRender` an asynchronous function, and then await the `getRemoteInclude` function

Comment: @undefined Thank you! I had tried versions of this but never quite got it right until just now. If you want to submit an answer i'll mark it as correct. Otherwise I will submit the answer